# How to show that $\mathbb{R}^3$ with two disjoint parallel lines removed has the same homotopy type as $N$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups, retraction

I am studying for an exam and came across a problem from a previous incarnation.

The problem is stated as follows:

> Let $L_1$ and $L_2$ be disjoint parallel lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let$ M=\mathbb{R}^3−(L_1\cup L_2)$.  Let $q\in M$. Let $C_1$ $C_2$ be disjoint parallel lines in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let $N=\mathbb{R}^3−(C_1\cup C_2)$.
>
> 1. Show that $\pi_1 M\cong \pi_1N$.
> 2. Show that $M$ and $N$ do not have the same homotopy type.
> 3. Show that $M−\{q\}$ has the same homotopy type as $N$.

First, I am farily certain that $C_1$ and $C_2$ should be circles rather than lines. I am assuming that $C_1$ and $C_2$ are disjoint and not linked.

1. I was able to show that $M$ and $N$ have the same fundamental group by first showing that $M$ deformation retracts to a bouquet of two circles. Similarly, $N$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^2\vee S^2 \vee S^1\vee S^1$. I can then use the Seifert van Kampen theorem to compute the fundamental groups.
2. For the second part, I computed the Euler characteristic of $M$ and $N$. Seeing as $\chi(M) = -1$ while $\chi(N) = 1$, these spaces are not homotopy equivalent.
3. This is where I get stuck. I already know that $M$ is homotopy equivalent to the bouquet of two circles, so I was hoping to show the same for $N$. However, I am unable to do this. Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: I think, you copied the problem incorrectly: As written, $M$ is obviously homeomorphic to $N$, so 2 and 3 are false.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I copied the problem correctly. As stated in my question: "First, I am fairly certain that 1 and 2 should be circles rather than lines."

Comment: I see. Then 3 is false. Maybe one is a line and the other is a circle?

Comment: @MoisheKohan Great to hear it! I had a feeling. I am not sure what the question should be, but at least I can do the part of the problem which is correct. Thank you for your help.